# Javascript issue calling function in timer

Tags: javascript, bots

I wrote some code to have a Discord bot mute and unmute users for a set amount of time. I know its probably not the prettiest as I am still pretty new, but it does work the way I want it to except that I would like it to send a reply in the chat once they are unmuted. If I take the line of code I wrote out of comment then I get an error that "message.reply is not a function" and the bot breaks. Im not sure how else to handle this. I looked through discord.js and cant find another way to get the bot to just respond on its own. I'm sure I'm just being dumb....Any help would be appreciated. This is my first attempt at a bot.

[picture of my code because I tried copying and pasting but it wouldn't let me send it even though I feel like it is formatted correctly. Again i am very new to this. thanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOdG4.jpg)

Comment: *"picture of my code because I tried copying and pasting but it wouldn't let me send it even though I feel like it is formatted correctly. Again i am very new to this. thanks"* - what was the issue when you tried to post the question?

Comment: It just said that the code wasn't formatted but I was unsure how to fix it in order to have it send. This is literally my second time asking a question. I tried copy and pasted and using code bricks but it wouldn't send so I just took a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the definition of unMute to inside the client.on('message' callback

like so

```
client.on('message', message => {
    const unMute = () => { ... etc ... };
    ... etc ...
})
```

Comment: I just tried that and now it still mutes them ok and then waits the set amount of time but then it breaks when it goes to unmute them and error says "return is not a function"

Comment: @N8Morton - I have no idea what `member.removeRole('......')` returns, so you'll need to figure out if what it returns has a function named `return` or not - not enough info in the question - besides - this has fixed the `message.reply` error the question is about, no mention of `member.removeRole('......').return` not being a function in your original question

Comment: Well yes I agree, but I only received that seconderror from trying your suggestion, so technically it doesn't really fix the problem in the question, but thanks for the help I appreciate it. take care.

Comment: @N8Morton yes, it does actually, this answers the problem you asked about. The fact that you have another issue is not CAUSED BY the first issue being fixed, the problem was always there, but it's only apparent because the first issue is fixed

Comment: @N8Morton - perhaps I could help with that if you show (**in the question**) what `member` is

Comment: I just moved a few other things around and got it working. What you said was the main issue and after moving some other things around it works as planned! Thanks for the help!